# When does my class need a build() method?

Tags: flutter

I understand the general approach to building UI layouts using Flutter. However, I'm still unclear which classes or UI widgets require a .build() method when I'm creating my own vs. using the defaults generated by the project.

I haven't found a clear explanation yet - even in the Flutter tutorials. They all seem to just gloss over how "the build method takes a BuildContext" and then go on to the next subject without explaining further.

Does anyone have a succinct explanation of the build method and when it is or isn't needed? And more specifically: what does it actually do?

Comment: In simple words, you need `build()` method if you want to draw something on screen

Comment: So could I put a build() method in each widget? In each class? Or just one build() at the topmost widget of the tree?

Comment: You use **buid()** to output something on screen when using a **StatelessWidget** or **StatefulWidget (inside it's State class)**.

Comment: If your class extends `StatelessWidget` or `StatefulWidget` (in common), then the class itself is a Widget. In Flutter everything is a widget. If you use case is limited, you can only have one `build()` method at the top of the tree like you said, and the complete screen can be shown with just one `build()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`build()` method describes the part of the user interface represented by this widget.

The framework calls this method in a number of different situations:

- After calling initState.
- After calling didUpdateWidget.
- After receiving a call to setState.
- After a dependency of this State object changes (e.g., an InheritedWidget referenced by the previous build changes).
  After calling deactivate and then reinserting the State object into the tree at another location.
  You can find more [Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/build.html)

**TLDR**: The build methode is used to create a new widget tree by placing the Widget reurned in the page tree. This method is essentially called when you create or update the widget (by calling `setState((){})`